# Alamofire Sort by date

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I try to do and apps that sort events 1th by distance and by date of the event with alamofire

I'm beginner with swift and sort by distance is done. Now I cannot sort by date.

for this, on my JSON, I have information like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "",    
    "eventDate1": "14/02/2018",
    "eventDate2": "26/03/2018",
    "eventDate3": "01/01/2018",
    "eventDate4": "",
    "eventDate5": "",
    ...
```

this is the date of the event (max 5 dates at the same time). I would like to show the event only 1 week before the date of the event. Not before one week and not after the date of the event. Anywhere if information is already added on the JSON.

My code in tableview is for the moment this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //géolocalisation
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    Alamofire.request("http://.../event2.json")
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let rawPersonList = response.result.value as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            for personData in rawPersonList {
                if let personObject = Person(fromData: personData) {
                    self._personList.append(personObject)
                }
            }
            if let currentPosition = self.positionUser{
                self._personList.sort(by: { (person1, person2) -> Bool in
                    let distancePerson1FromUser = currentPosition.distance(from: person1.location)
                    let distancePerson2FromUser = currentPosition.distance(from: person2.location)

                    return distancePerson1FromUser < distancePerson2FromUser
                })
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            print(response.result.error as Any)
        }
    }

}
```

Someone can help me how I can do this? Thanks

Comment: There is a whole lot going on here. You shuold really break it down ino some simlper methods.

Comment: thanks Alexander for your answer. What do you mine?

Comment: This one `viewDidLoad` function: Configures a location delegate, makes a network request, parses its result, sorts a list of objects by position, reloads a table. You should encapsulate these parts into smaller functions. Nobody wants to work with something so hectic

Comment: Ok, thanks you for your answer. I am a beginner with code and I'll take care of you say. It's very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this one my sound weird, but here it goes: Your best bet will be to forget about `responseJSON`, use `responseString` instead and run your own `Codable` protocol object. The latter can be demonstrated in a Playground as follows:

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "",
    "eventDate1": "14/02/2018",
    "eventDate2": "26/03/2018",
    "eventDate3": "01/01/2018"
}]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct SpecialEvent: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let eventDate1 : Date
    let eventDate2 : Date?
    let eventDate3 : Date?
    let eventDate4 : Date?
    let eventDate5 : Date?
}

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

do {
    let evt = try decoder.decode([SpecialEvent].self, from: jsonData)
    print(evt)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This simplifies your parsing greatly, staying pretty close to the `JSON`-structure you proposed. However I am not sure if it is a good idea to keep with your `eventDate` keys, it looks like an ugly kludge. Why the artificial limitation on 5 dates? Ok, there may be UI-reasons for that, but that should just influence your display, not your data structure. If you can control your server response (and you seem to be able to) you should consider having a `"dates"`-array with either just strings or maybe another dictionary (e.g. `Codable` object in Swift) with additional information (e.g. location, time etc.) This will be more flexible and you won't have to deal with optionals in the way you would have to in the current structure.

Note that your original structure would not be parseable using my simple data structure, since a present key will require a valid date. If you desire otherwise you will probably have to write a custom initializer for it.